# C# attach event handling with additional parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, action

**PREFACE**

I have a Windows form Button that exposes the event OnClick (object sender, EventArgs e).
In my application I can handle this by using the classic event handling technique of C#:

```
// Button Creation
Button button = new Button();
button.Click += MyEventHandler;
```

Then Windows Form ask me for an handler with the following signature:

```
public void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Suppose that I would like to use lambda expression to do this I can use the syntax:

```
button.Click += (sender, args) =>
{
  // execute the code
};
```

The drawback of this is that I can't unsubscribe from a Lambda expression.

**QUESTION**

What I would like to do is to have an utility class that will allow me to handle any Click event plus using an additional Action as a parameter. So I would like to write something like this:

```
button.Click += MyUtility.Click(() 
    => {
        // the custom code the Click event will execute
    })
```

Can I do it in somehow?

Comment: Why go through all of that when you already have a solution? Don't use a lambda if you need to unsubscribe, simple.

Comment: You didn't answer the question at all ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the lambda expression to a local variable or field.

For example:

```
EventHandler handler = (sender, args) =>
{
  // execute the code
};

button.Click += handler;
button.Click -= handler;
```

If you want to unsubscribe inside the handler, you'll need to assign `handler` to `null`, then to the lambda, to avoid definite assignment issues.